# Is it possible to access private nuget server from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I wanted to set up a pipeline but it fails at the NuGet Restore  with the following

```
Errors in packages.config projects

    Unable to find version '1.0.0.5' of package 'mypackage'.

      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'mypackage.1.0.0.5' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
```

This package is actually stored on a local NuGet server of my company  (internal network) not available from the internet.

Is it possible for Azure DevOps to access these packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. You´ll need to have a Self-Hosted Agent ==> e.g. Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops
2. It makes sense if nuget is stored in a local Nuget repo
3. Setup Nuget.config to point it to your repo.
   4, In the NuGet Restore task be sure to select the Feeds to use --> 'Feeds in my NuGet.config'

==> Example for Private-Repo stuff: https://medium.com/@churi.vibhav/creating-and-using-a-local-nuget-package-repository-9f19475d6af8

Comment: From artifacts in devops, I created a new feed for nuget.exe, and followed the instructions including creating a nuget.config and placing it in the solution directory, but at the last step what do I specify as <packagePath> `nuget.exe push -Source "tempnuget" -ApiKey az <packagePath>` I tried putting the path to my local feed (as url) but says the file doesn't exist

Comment: => https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/packagemanagement/ ===> Step 16 ==> API Key = any String.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for pointing me to the self hosted agent.

Comment: Very nice :) Can you then please mark my answer as the answer? Thx :)